# Updating a custom Workflow field

Tags: list, workflow, custom-list, task-list

I have inherited a list. It's on sharepoint 2016 with designer 2013. It's updated via a Workflow. I have a column called 'Outcome' which I need to change the status of on a few of the items. However, I can't find a) the workflow b)the actual column! Any idea how I could find the column and how I could update the status on a few of the items? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A) to fnd the workflow, go to the list.  In the ribbon under List, there should be a workflow button.  Click it and it should show you if there are any workflows.

B) to find the column, modify any of the views on the list and see if the column is listed in there.  If so, check the box to show it in the view.

Comment: Thanks, but...
a) yes, done that, no workflows showing
b) yes the column is showing in the view, that's not a problem, I need to edit what's in the item fields for that item. So for item 1,2,3 I need to change what's in the Outcome column